# Need columns list whose value is greater than 0 in pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I have below data:

```
>>> dfStd1.show()
+---+----+------+-------+-----------------------------------------------+------+
| id|Name|Seq_Id|Carrier|CASE WHEN (NOT (Seq_Id = 1)) THEN 0 ELSE 12 END|string|
+---+----+------+-------+-----------------------------------------------+------+
|  0|   0|     0|      2|                                              0|     0|
+---+----+------+-------+-----------------------------------------------+------+
```

So, here I need names of column which has value greater than 0. Here, for eg I need `Carrier` column I need to store such values in a list. I tried below code but doesn't work and also referred many SO links but no luck:

```
>>> dfStd1[(dfStd1 > 0).any(axis=1)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'DataFrame' and 'int'
```

It throws error as above. I even tried to convert it into pandas then filter it out but no result.

Comment: Do you have only one row in the column?

Comment: There might be multiple columns with more than 0 values.

Answer (score 0):

First you need columns which are numeric:

```
schema = {col: col_type for col, col_type in df.dtypes}
numeric_cols = [
            col
            for col, col_type in schema.items()
            if col_type in "int double bigint".split()
        ]
```

Then you can count number of elements in a column that are greater than 0 by using:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col

count_cols_gt_zero = [
            json.loads(x)
            for x in self.data.select(
                [count(when(col(c) > 0, c)).alias(c) for c in self.schema]
            )
            .toJSON()
            .collect()
        ][0]
```

Then finally:

```
final = [x for x, y in count_cols_gt_zero.items() if y > 0]
```

Comment: Thank you for help. I will test it and let you know